# Keeping track of min and max heaps in a Priority Queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm trying to implement a priority queue that allows for deletion of the min and the max values. I'm doing this by creating two heaps within the PQ object and two additional arrays to keep track of the location of the same values in each heap. I'm confused about how to maintain those two arrays when performing a sink, swim, or exchange.

Online, I found the comparison of the two arrays to be a[N] = b[ab[N]] and b[N] = a[ba[N]], but the problem is I don't understand those equations. If someone can offer me some insight, I think I would then be able to maintain the arrays.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class MyMinMaxPQ<Key extends Comparable<Key>> {

private int N = 0;  // number of items on priority queue
private Key[] a;    // minheap
private Key[] b;    // maxheap
private int[] ab;   // index a to b: a[i] == b[ab[i]]
private int[] ba;   // index b to a: b[i] == a[ba[i]]

public MyMinMaxPQ(int maxN) {   //constructor
    a = (Key[]) new Comparable[maxN+1];
    b = (Key[]) new Comparable[maxN+1];
    ab = new int[maxN+1];
    ba = new int[maxN+1];
}

public Key delMin() {
    Key min = b[1];
    exch(b, 1, N--);
    a[N+1] = null;
    sink(a, 1);
    return min;
}

public Key delMax() {
    Key max = a[1];     // Retrieve max key from top.
    exch(a, 1, N--);    // Exchange with last item.
    a[N+1] = null;      // Avoid loitering.
    sink(a, 1);         // Restore heap property.
    return max;
}

public void insert(Key item) {
    a[++N] = item;
    b[++N] = item;
    swim(a, N);
    swim(b, N);
    a[N] = b[ab[N]];
    b[N] = a[ba[N]];
}

private void swim(Key[] heap, int k) {
    while (k > 1 && less(heap, k/2, k)) {
        exch(heap, k/2, k);
        k = k/2;
    }
}

/**
 * Moves the numbers down the heap
 * @param heap the heap that the sink will occur on
 * @param k the index number on the heap
 */
private void sink(Key[] heap, int k) {
    while (2*k <= N) {
        int j = 2*k;
        if (j < N && less(heap, j, j+1)) j++;
        if (!less(heap, k, j)) break;
        exch(heap, k, j);
        k = j;
    }
}

/**
 * @param i = first integer to be compared
 * @param j = second integer to be compared
 * @return <0 : i precedes j; =0 : i and j are equal; >0 : j precedes i
 */
private boolean less(Key[] heap, int i, int j) {
    if (heap == a) {
        return a[i].compareTo(a[j]) <= 0; 
    } else {
        return b[i].compareTo(b[j]) >= 0; 
    }
}

/** exchange the two values at indexes i and j in the same heap */
private void exch(Key[] heap, int i, int j) { 
    Key t = heap[i];
    heap[i] = heap[j];
    heap[j] = t;
}

/** Is the priority queue empty? */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return N == 0;
}

/** Return the number of items on the priority queue. */
public int size() {
    return N;
}
```

}

Comment: Unless there is a homework constraint I would just maintain two internal PriorityQueues, one with an inverting comparator.

Comment: @EJP Yes, it's a homework constraint.